# GA Enhance Ecommerce Product List Performance

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using Enhanced Ecommerce and I want to know how good my product lists perform. Below a screenshot of the **product list performance** section.

[image: product performance list]

You can see that I've set up three lists:

- productgroep default (Standard product listing)
- productgroep filtered (Product listing with filters used)
- detail view (this is actually a product detail page, so no listing.)

There is also a:

- (not set) product list name, this one comes by default.

Now when I click on a product in a list, it counts in the column **Product List Clicks**, all fine.
One can also add a product directly to the cart when the list is shown, so these are also measured and shown in the column **Product Adds To Card**.

Now when the product is purchased, it counts the **Product Checkouts, Unique Purchases and Product Revenue** in the product List **(not set)**.

When the product is added to the cart directly from a list, I also do:

```
ga("ec:setAction", "click", {
  "list": "productgroep default"
});
```

Why doesn't GA add these purchases to the correct product list?

Comment: Is it possible, that you have a typo? Your Code doesn´t work for me, but this (without " for list):
ga('ec:setAction', 'click', {list: 'productgroep default'});

Comment: @DanielS, I'm changing the double quote to a single quote. I also noticed in my code that I was using `ec:addImpression` without setting the `list` value.

Comment: You have to provide a valid object to the tracker. Like this

gtag('event', 'purchase', {
  "transaction_id": "123",
  "affiliation": "store",
  "value": 1.00,
  "currency": "USD",
  "tax": 1.24,
  "shipping": 0,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "P12345",
      "name": "Name",
      "list_name": "listname",
      "brand": "Google",
      "category": "T-Shirts",
      "variant": "Black",
      "list_position": 1,
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": '2.0'
    }
  ]
});
Check this doc:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-ecommerce

Answer (score 1):

When product is clicked from list page, do:

```
ga('ec:addProduct', {
'id': id,
'name': name,
'category': 'Apparel',
'brand': 'Nike',
'variant': 'black',
'position': 1
});
ga('ec:setAction', 'click', {list: listName});
ga('send', 'event', 'UX', 'click', 'Results');
```

When the product is added to the cart directly from a list, do:

```
ga('ec:addProduct', {
'id': id,
'name': name,
'category': 'Apparel',
'brand': 'Nike',
'variant': 'black',
'position': 1
});
ga('ec:setAction', 'click', {list: listName});
ga('send', 'event', 'UX', 'click', 'Add to Cart Catalog');
```

On product details page load, do :

```
ga('ec:addProduct', {
'id': id,
'name': name,
'category': 'Apparel',
'brand': 'Nike',
'variant': 'black'
});
ga('ec:setAction', 'detail');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: This is just a copy and paste from previous answers. Also this is no EE or GTM DayaLayer

Comment: I have enlisted only necessary steps needed to track correctly, and why GTM Datalayer required ?

Answer (score 1):

The attribution in the enhanced eCommerce is a little trick, it makes list attribution and promotion attribution.

Relate to the list attribution, the purchase is recursively attributed to the last list **viewed** that contains the id of the product. So, even if you access the cart through one page, f you open another page that contains the product id before making the purchase, the attribution will change. With the promotion attribution is kind of different, the purchase is attributed to the last promotion clicked.

Make sure of the structure of the enhanced eCommerce object as well.

There's a full explanation [here](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/attribution-enhanced-ecommerce-reports/). This blog has a lot of information about it.